# Maximum width on a task pane Windows Forms

Tags: c#, vsto

I have made a test VSTO Office Addin which contains a task pane. Is it possible to have a maximum width on a vertical task bar.

My code is as follows

```
        var taskPaneView = new TaskPane.TaskPaneView();
        var myTaskPane= Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes.Add(taskPaneView, "Create");            
        myTaskPane.Visible = true;

        taskPaneView.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(202, 57, 4);
        taskPaneView.Width = 100;
```

Answer (score -1):

In normal [windows controls there is property called Dock which u can set](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.dockstyle(v=vs.110).aspx)

`ctrl.Dock = DockStyle.Buttom` 
In yr case, u need https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.customtaskpane.dockposition.aspx I guess

```
myCustomTaskPane.DockPosition =
        Office.MsoCTPDockPosition.msoCTPDockPositionFloating;

myCustomTaskPane.DockPosition.DockPositionRestrict = msoCTPDockPositionRestrictNoChange;
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa942864.aspx

It's hard to test since creating office app is needed.

Comment: Hi thanks for answer my question. I have made a VSTO Office add-in PowerPoint application so I should be able to test it. added this line in `myTaskPane.DockPositionRestrict = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoCTPDockPositionRestrict.msoCTPDockPositionRestrictNoChange;` however I can still change the width of the task pane. I have also set the width like so `myTaskPane.Width = 50;`